# "svn up" equivalent of git

Tags: git

I have deleted some files by mistake and want to recover them.  Note that I  **never** push the repository to some remote, because it is just a local repository.

```
  modified:   .svn/entries
#       deleted:    JavaTVServiceXlet.java
#       deleted:    TestSIGetProgramSchedule.java
#       deleted:    TestSIRetriveAll.java
#       deleted:    XletTestSIGetProgramSchedule.java
#       deleted:    XletTestSIRetriveAll.java
#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `git checkout -- [file]` to recover the last version in your repository.  **If you have no other changes at all** you can `git reset --hard HEAD` to unwind everything (even modified files) to the last local checkin.

Comment: Be careful with `git reset --hard` as there is **no** undoing it if you have not pushed, often doing a soft reset (the default) is just as useful as then you can review what has changed and act accordingly on each file.

Comment: And isn't it `git checkout -- <file>`?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: You can omit the `--` if `<file>` is unambiguous, but it's good practice to always use `--`.

Answer (score 5):

You can recover an individual file with:

```
git checkout -- JavaTVServiceXlet.java
```

... or to restore all the files that are have been deleted, you could do:

```
git ls-files -z --deleted | xargs -0 -n 1 git checkout --
```

The latter command generates a list of the deleted files, separated with NUL bytes, and pipes that to `xargs -0 -n 1`, which will run `git checkout -- <FILENAME>` for each file in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with `git checkout <file>`, as Ben Jackson suggested, or you can use `git reset -- <file>`. Either one should do what you want.

Checking in and pulling from a remote, as suggested by eLobato, is overly complex and unnecessary, as all the necessary information is already on your local machine.